# If a property is defined as copy, do I still need to do a copy when assigning to the ivar?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, declared-property

Suppose I have a property defined as `@property (copy) NSString *name`.

Suppose I have a `init` method defined as below.

```
-(instancetype) initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {
      _name = [name copy]; //Do I need this copy or will ARC do it automatically?
   }
   return self;
}
```

Do I need the copy in the commented line or will ARC handle it based on the `copy` in the property declaration just like it would in the synthesized setter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `copy` applies to the property's synthesized setter method, not the backing instance variable.

Since you are bypassing the property in the `initWithName:` method and assigning directly to the instance variable, the `copy` isn't applied automatically.

In order to honor the contract that the value is copied, you should explicitly call `copy` when you directly assign a value to the instance variable. None of this has to do with ARC (or MRC). It's all about the contract you defined on the property.

tl;dr - yes, you should call `copy` in the code you posted.